# How can I allow drag and drop over the whole containing element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've tried to make a custom file upload input. The goal was to just have it be better looking and and enable the whole container to have files dropped onto it.

My issue is this, I want the input onChange event to be triggered when a file is dropped anywhere inside of the containing div.file-upload.
However, the event is not triggered when the file is dropped over top of any of the non-input elements.
See the image below - input onChange is not triggered anywhere within the areas circled in purple.

Any suggestions on how I can make the input onChange triggered even if dropped in the purple areas?

[image]

Thanks!

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Button from '../Button';
import './FileUpload.scss';
import XLSX from 'xlsx';

const FileUpload = ({ changed }) => {
  const [selectedFileName, setSelectedFileName] = useState('');
  const [fileIsHoveringInput, setFileIsHoveringInput] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const input = document.getElementById('file-input');
    if (input) {
      input.addEventListener('drop', drop);
      input.addEventListener('dragenter', dragenter);
      input.addEventListener('dragleave', dragleave);
    }
  });

  const drop = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(false);
  };

  const dragenter = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(true);
  };

  const dragleave = () => {
    setFileIsHoveringInput(false);
  };

  const handleChange = event => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = onloadEvent => {
      const content = onloadEvent.target.result;
      const workBook = XLSX.read(content, { type: 'binary' });
      const sheet = workBook.SheetNames[0];
      const workSheet = workBook.Sheets[sheet];
      const data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workSheet, { header: 1 });
      setSelectedFileName(file.name);
      changed(data);
    };

    if (file) {
      reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
  };

  const determineLabelToUse = () => {
    if (selectedFileName) {
      return selectedFileName;
    } else {
      return 'Drag & drop file, or';
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`file-upload ${fileIsHoveringInput ? 'hover' : ''}`}>
        <input
          type='file'
          id='file-input'
          name='image_uploads'
          accept='.xls, .xlsx, .csv'
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div className='icon-container'>
          <div className='icon' data-icon='upload' />
        </div>
        <label htmlFor='file-input'>{determineLabelToUse()}</label>
        <Button
          id='secondary-button'
          type='secondary'
          disabled={fileIsHoveringInput}
        >
          {selectedFileName ? 'Replace File' : 'Choose File'}
        </Button>
        <p>(.xls, .xlsx, .csv)</p>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default FileUpload;
```

Here is the stylesheet:

```
@mixin core-rules {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #acabab;

  :hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  input {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
  }

  label {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  p {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }

  #secondary-button {
    position: relative;
    top: 21px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }

  .-oneX-icon {
    position: relative;
    height: 32px;
    width: 32px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 15px;
  }
}

.file-upload {
  @include core-rules;
}

.file-upload.hover {
  @include core-rules;
  border: 2px dashed #acabab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own question.
The other, non-input, elements were in front of the input element.
So when a file was hovering over, for example, the p tag, then the expected event wasn't being triggered.

So, to address this, I simply added an additional rule in the css for the input element, which was:
`z-index: 5;`
Allowing the input element to be in front of all the other elements.